# Why does Command Prompt script stop if pandas is imported?

Tags: python, pandas, import, command, command-prompt

I am trying to execute python scripts from the Command Prompt on my Windows computer. This works just fine *unless* I use pandas in my python script.

for example, I have the following code

```
import random, CardDeckGraphic, time, csv


keyword = ''
while keyword != 'stop':
    print('say something')
    keyword = input()
```

which runs great, it prints "say something" until I type "stop"
However if I have the exact same script but import pandas...

```
import random, CardDeckGraphic, time, csv
import pandas

keyword = ''
while keyword != 'stop':
    print('say something')
    keyword = input()
```

it doesn't work. I don't get an error, I just get nothing. I have no idea why pandas is messing up my script. I can run it just fine in Spyder.

*note, I know I don't need pandas in the python example above, this is a sample of the problem I have when running other scripts.

result when I don't import pandas
[command line success](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PDq3J.png)

result when I do import pandas
[command line fail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YQJqz.png)

Comment: This sounds like a problem with your pandas installation, it's getting stuck when you try to import it.

Comment: Do you have another file in that folder named `pandas.py` or something?

Comment: I don't have another file named pandas.py
Should I reinstall pandas? How would I do that? (note, pandas does work when I use it in a python IDE like Spyder)

Comment: @TonyWalley Did you ever find a solution to this problem? I'm having the exact same issue, an even simpler program:
`import pandas as pd`
`print("Hello world")`
Doesn't do anything, doesn't throw any errors either.

Comment: For future reference, it seems there was some issue with my python/pip installation, I fully removed all pip packages, pip cache, and python, reboot the machine, then installed anaconda, this fixed the issue for me.